# How do I disable the screenshot sound?

Tags: sound, screenshot

I am not holding a camera, I do not need to hear a shutter sound to know I pressed the Print Screen key.

Other suggestions on the site encourage people to disable event sounds, but I use these.
So it something I can hack out of the sound theme?

Comment: This really depends on what DE environment you are using, GNOME Shell, GNOME 2, KDE, and so on.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Either disable system sound effects or, I am assuming you want to disable only the screen shot sound, move or rename `/usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/camera-shutter.oga`

```
sudo mv /usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/camera-shutter.oga /usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/camera-shutter-disabled.oga
```

Comment: Ta, that worked after a restart.

Comment: In my case the file was named differently, but still on the same folder  `sudo mv /usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/screen-capture.oga /usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/screen-capture-disabled.oga `
I also had to reboot, thanks for the knowledge.

Comment: Neither works in 17.10 for me

Comment: Worked on Ubuntu 18.04 like a charm.

Comment: works on ubuntu 20.04

Comment: works on ubuntu Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: Is this answer meant for GNOME's screenshot functionality?

Answer (score 8):

Another proposed solution is by doing the following:

1. Run the command: `sudo mv /usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/camera-shutter.oga /usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/camera-shutter-backup.oga`
2. Run the command after:  `sudo ffmpeg -f lavfi -i anullsrc -t 0.5 -c:a libvorbis /usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/camera-shutter.oga`

ffmpeg comes with Ubuntu on a fresh installation, and the plugin anullsrc generates silence, outputting it as an Ogg Vorbis file format using the libvorbis library. It needs to be named as an OGA file, due to symbolic links associated with it. It needs to be 0.5 seconds long, otherwise, it may take a while for the screenshot feature to finish its job.

Tested on a clean installation of Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32017827/how-to-create-silent-ogg-audio-file

Comment: "ffmpeg comes with Ubuntu on a fresh installation" Can confirm this is not the case on 20.04. Default installation.

Comment: Yeah, I think it was starting around Bionic, `ffmpeg` needs to be separately installed. You will have to do `sudo apt-get install ffmpeg`.

Answer (score 7):

Although I've not tested it, but it seems that `/usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/screen-capture.oga` is the sound you're talking about.

Try renaming or moving it.

Also, in the properties of `screen-capture.oga` it is said it has as target the file `camera-shutter.oga`. so, it is a link to the later. i guess touching any of these would eliminate the sound

Comment: Sorry, just saw your answer. Please edit to add the the file I reference in my answer and I can then delete mine. (both sound the same!)

Comment: after renaming it and log out/in it is solved. this answer came first and i will check it as definitive

Comment: @izx. `add the file  I reference in my answer`. does this mean that both sound files should be renamed/removed or just one?

Comment: @cipricus: if this worked for you, great, no need to change the other -- that used to be the "old" screenshot sound file. Good job green 7, upvoted!

Answer (score 4):

1. Click on the sound icon at the upper right corner of the screen.
2. Now click on the sound setting.
3. Now click on sound effect
   [image: mute screenshot sound in ubuntu]

   **Now mute sound from here.**
4. You have done. No Screenshot sound from now onwards.

Comment: This disables all sound effects. I guess the question is about disabling only this particular sound.

Comment: In my Ubuntu 16.04 it only disables screenshot sound effects.

Answer (score 1):

You temporarily rename the shutter sound file:

```
sudo mv -i /usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/screen-capture.oga /usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/screen-capture-disabled.oga
```

The use of -i helps to avoid accidentially overriding an old backup you have.

**Important:** You may need to logout and login again, in case the sound is cached in memory. For me login/logout was sufficient, but if that is not sufficient try rebooting.

To reactivate it move the sound file back:

```
sudo mv -i /usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/screen-capture-disabled.oga /usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/screen-capture.oga
```

You may need to logout/login again.

Note: In my system (Ubuntu 20.04) screen-capture.oga is a link to camera-shutter.oga, that's why the solutions moving instead camera-shutter.oga work as well.