# How to remove sound in Take Screenshot?

Tags: sound, screenshot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I disable the screenshot sound?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140200/how-do-i-disable-the-screenshot-sound)

After reinstalling Lubuntu 12.04 and Take Screenshot, I have a typical picture camera shot sound whenever I use the program, and cannot find the settings to change that. I do not remember ever having to remove the sound during using it before.